# Using Salesforce Event data in Journey Exit Criteria

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm building a sales appointment journey, I'm tracking each scheduling of an appointment as a separate SFDC Event with a status (e.g. if someone schedules an appointment then reschedules that results in 2 Events one with a status 'Scheduled' and one 'Rescheduled'). I'd like Contacts to exit the Journey if they cancel their appointment or the appointment happens (status == 'Completed' || status == 'Cancelled')

**The Issue:** When I try to define the exit criteria for this Journey, I only have access to Contact data and while I can navigate Contact > SFDC > SFDContact > SFDCEvent there may be multiple Events associated with the Contact and I only want to watch for the status of the Event that dropped the Contact into the Journey.

I've considered automating some data updates on the SFDC side to maintain the current EventId for comparison, but this seems like it would be error-prone and add the complexity of updating data on the SFDC side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the Journey Builder Exit Criteria setting to configure this.

Instead configure Decision Split activity to match the Contact Data `EventID` with the Journey Data `EventID` and an additiona criteria to check for the Event Status from the Contact Data.

This way you will match the `EventID` for the Contact currently in the Decision Split activity and are able to check for the Synchronised Data Extension for the updated status.