# Journey Builder and Exit Criteria configuration

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Fairly basic scenario. In Sales Cloud, a custom record is created or updated (boolean field equals `TRUE`) it will inject the related Contact to the Journey and that's that. This specific Journey allows multiple entries.

What is the most sensible way to Exit a Contact from a Journey if same example record is changed in Sales Cloud, so that the boolean field now equals `FALSE`?

It seems that the [**Exit Criteria**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_exit_criteria.htm&type=5) is fairly limited, by allowing to check only Contact Data path which means it's not usable for Journies allowing multiple entries for the same Contacts.

Same with Decision Split activity with [**Attribute-to-Attribute comparison**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_attribute_comparison.htm&type=5), as this does not allow to check nullable fields.

Similar question was raised in [February](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/209483/using-salesforce-event-data-in-journey-exit-criteria) about using SF source based entries and Exit Criterias but recieved no attention.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using decision split, you don't need to perform attribute-to-attribute comparison as the use case here is to check a value from Sales Cloud. 
Also, if your journey has waits before the decision split, then this method would work as if a value is changed in Sales Cloud, in order to get it synchronized into Marketing Cloud and update the DE, it will take some time(min. 15 minutes). Then in order to get the updated value, you need to create Attribute group in Data designer to link your DE. 
In Decision Split you need to use Contact Data instead of journey data to check if that particular field is true or false. If false, then exit the journey.

We had this exact scenario in our implementation and this method worked absolutely fine.

Comment: Attribute comparison is necessary in order to determine the correct record is evaluated, in cases there are multiple of the same Contact in the Journey. Anyway since my scenario already had the Salesforce Attribute Groups (due to being primary BU) all that was required was to match the custom record ID's and then the field value from Contact Data path.